# Autoscroll on mousedrag

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js

Created D3 tree. Horizontal scroll bar is not working on drag selection of tree node in Firefox 37. In chrome horizontal scroll is working on drag selection.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="tree-container" id="treeId"></div>
</div>

$('.tree-container').css('overflow', 'auto');

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").call(dragListener).attr(
            "class", "node").attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    }).on("mouseenter", nodeMouseEnter).on("mouseleave", nodeMouseLeave)
            .on('click', click).attr('id', function(d) {
                return d.nodeId;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Code is here :

```
 <div id="outerFrame">
    <div id="innerFrame">
        <svg width="600" height="600">
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #outerFrame{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid red;
       overflow: auto;
}

 #innerFrame{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

rect{
    fill: green;
}
```

JS code :

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart)
    .on("drag", dragmove)
    .on("dragend", dragend);

function dragstart() {
  d3.select(this).style("border", "1px solid red");
}

function dragmove(d) {
    var svg = d3.select("svg").node(),
        $parent = $('#outerFrame'),
        w = $parent.width(), h = $parent.height(),
        sL = $parent.scrollLeft(), sT = $parent.scrollTop();

    var coordinates = d3.mouse(svg),
        x = coordinates[0],
        y = coordinates[1];

    if (x > w + sL) {
        $parent.scrollLeft(x - w);  
    } else if (x < sL) {
        $parent.scrollLeft(x);
    }

    if (y > h + sT) {
        $parent.scrollTop(y - h);
    } else if (y < sT) {
        $parent.scrollTop(y);
    }

    d3.select(this).attr({
        x: x - 50,
        y: y - 25
    })
}

function dragend() {
  d3.select(this).style("border", null);
}

d3.select("svg")
    .append("rect")
    .attr({x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50})
    .call(drag);
```